# Interfaces to methods in C#?

Tags: c#

In C# language, let's assume that I have an interface **ISender** and a class that implements this interface. Also I want my class that implements ISender have **Send()** *method that must invoke another method* like **ValidateContent()** within itself.

```
public interface ISender {
    void Send(); // How to declare that Send() must invoke ValidateContent within itself?
}

public class EmailReportSender : ISender {
    public void Send(){
        ValidateContent();
        // Do stuff
    }
}
public class IPhoneNotificationReportSender : ISender {
    public void Send(){
        ValidateContent();
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't ask a question?  But it seems like you want an abstract class more than an interface.

Comment: so what? what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that in an interface.  What you would do is flip the logic upside down, and use the template pattern.  Have one base method that defined the 'algorithm' that needs to happen, and defer points that need to be unique to subclasses:

```
public abstract class SenderBase
{
    public void Send()
    {
        ValidateContent();
        CustomStuff();
    }

    protected abstract void CustomStuff();
}

public sealed class EmailReportSender : SenderBase
{
    protected override void CustomStuff()
    {

    }
}
public sealed class IPhoneNotificationReportSender : SenderBase
{
    protected override void CustomStuff()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, and uncannily, almost the exact same code example.

Comment: Actually, I never got a chance to publish mine. Looks like a  BJ Myers was on the same wavelength though.

Answer (score 1):

An interface describes the methods that must be implemented, but has no say in *how* they are implemented or what the implementation must actually do.

An abstract class, however, allows you to define behavior while still using abstract methods as points of extensibility.  A combination of non-abstract public methods and abstract protected methods may do what you want:

```
public abstract class Sender
{
    public void Send()
    {
        ValidateContent();
        DoSend();
    }

    private void ValidateContent()
    {
        // Put validation code here
    }

    protected abstract void DoSend();
}

public class EmailReportSender : Sender
{
    protected override void DoSend()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
public class IPhoneNotificationReportSender : Sender
{
    protected override void DoSend()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like a job for unit testing.  Your compiler isn't going to enforce it for you, but if the rule exists, then it should be tested accordingly.  The below uses Moq.

```
[TestFixture]
public class EmailReportSenderTests
{
    [Test]
    public void EmailReportSender_Send_CallsValidateContent()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ISender>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Send()).Verifiable();

        var sender = new EmailReportSender(mock.Object);
        sender.Send();

        mock.Verify(m => m.ValidateContent());
    }
}
```

I haven't tried that snippet, so it may have typos, but you get the idea.